# Vuex getters used in a component show errors in console because at the time of their calling, the Vuex state properties are still null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I assign results from GET requests to my Vuex state properties, so it's only natural that they're not available instantly, however, I also have a getter like this one:

```
findChampion: (state) => (id) => {
     let championId = id.toString();
     let champion = Object.values(state.champions).find(value => value.key === championId);

     return champion
 }
```

Which is called from a component of mine and it seems that at the time of the first calling, the `state.champions` property is still `null` which gives me loads of errors in my component.

This is how I call the getter from my component:

```
<img :src="'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/' + $store.getters.version + '/img/champion/' + $store.getters.findChampion(this.match.mainParticipant.championId).image.full" alt="">
```

So how can I make it so my component waits for my Vuex state to be not null before calling the getter?

The error is `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: `v-if="$store.state.champions.length"` should do it for ya

Comment: @Ohgodwhy if the `state.champions` is null, calling `.length` will endup in different error. Do `<img v-if="$store.state.champions && $store.state.champions.length"...`

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind.

1. Set the default state value to something other than null. So for this error:

`TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Try setting the default value of that state to `{}`.

2. Add a check somewhere that the state value is what you expect before you try to use it.

So for example in your `findChampion` function you can check the state value first like:

```js
findChampion: (state) => (id) => {
     if (!state.champions) {
         return []; // or whatever is appropriate to return
     }

     let championId = id.toString();
     let champion = Object.values(state.champions).find(value => value.key === championId);

     return champion
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check with state.champions exists before. Something like this:

```
findChampion: (state) => (id) => {
  let championId = id.toString()
  let champion = state.champions ? Object.values(state.champions).find(value => value.key === championId) : []
  return champion
}
```

: [] return a empty array, you can return null, false, undefined or any other thing you need.

Check if this works please, and tell me.